# SIGSTOP does not work when scripted

Tags: shell, kill, raise

I have a really huge archive, which must be extracted file by file and further processed. I don't have enough memory to extract the whole archive (neither in RAM nor on the flash) - thus I wrote a small application which stops (`raise(SIGSTOP)`) after each extracted file. An equivalent could be this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main() {
    printf("started.\n"); fflush(stdout);
    sleep(2);                             // extracting archive
    printf("stopping\n"); fflush(stdout);
    raise(SIGSTOP);                       // stopping
    printf("resume + done\n"); fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

This works fine while I execute this in the terminal:

```
$ gcc -o dosleep main.c
$ ./dosleep 
started.
stopping

[1]+  Stopped                 ./dosleep
$ fg
./dosleep
resume + done
$
```

But when calling the method from a script, the command never returns:

```
$ cat doit.sh 
#!/bin/sh
echo "STARTING"
./dosleep
echo "BACK"
$ ./doit.sh 
STARTING
started.
stopping

^C^C^C^C^C^C
```

Why do terminal and script behave so differently? Is there a way to change this behavior?

Thanks, Karl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Job control is off-by-default in noninteractive shells, but you can enable it explicitly:

```
set -m
```

Thus, if we modify your script to add either the `set -m` line or a `-m` on the shebang as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash -m
./start-delay
echo BACK
```

...then `BACK` is emitted after `stopping`.

---

Quoting from the bash man page [section on `set`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html), emphasis added:

> `-m` Monitor  mode.   Job  control is enabled.  *This option is on by default for interactive shells on systems that support it* (see JOB CONTROL above).  All processes run in a separate process group. When a background job completes, the shell prints a line containing its exit status.

Comment: when calling the script not from the login-shell you have to start it with `setsid sh -c 'myscript.sh < /dev/tty1'`, otherwise you get `Can't access tty; job control turned off`

Comment: @Charly, ...well, not so much "not from the login shell" as "from somewhere without a TTY". The two are somewhat orthogonal -- it's possible to have a login shell with no TTY, or a TTY with no login shell.